# ACES workflow in Blender

Tags: workflow, color-management

Q.: What is the correct way to import ACES 2065-1 encoded EXR files into Blender whilst keeping the look identical to what I saw when exporting from Davinci Resolve?

In both application I select the output transform to be Rec.709 but upon importing in Blender, it looks different.

Unless I select in Blender as input color space for the footage "ACES AP0".. but internally, will Blender automatically work with AP1 (ACEScg primaries - same as Resolve seems to do but in ACEScct) or not?

Comment: Asfar as I know, the primaries in blender are sRGB/709, the color space setting you mention must be converting from ACES to sRGB. Internally the color space is not ACES.

Comment: I did install OCIO ACES 1.0.3; or are these simply input & output transforms rather than actual working spaces for Blender? 

thanks!

Comment: Blender's reference space is linear rec.709, so all the transforms (yes, they are transforms) in its default OCIO config are from/to that reference.
As fas as I know every mention to ACES in Blender's default OCIO config is outdated and wrong and should be avoided.